# how to split already opened gvim file

Tags: vim

So I am using lubuntu and have gvim installed. Suppose I have two files in the current directory, file1.py and file2.py (both python files) and I want to open file1. So I do

```
gvim file1.py
```

and it opens, which is good. But now suppose I want to open file2.py by vertically (or horizontally) splitting the already open gvim window into two, how would I go about doing so from the terminal?

Also, how do I close only one file which is open splitscreen? So say I have file1.py and file2.py open in one window (vertically split) and I want to close file1.py?

Comment: This is addressed over at superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/486532/how-to-open-files-in-vertically-horizontal-split-windows-in-vim-from-the-command

Comment: Right, but when I do gvim -o file2.py or gvim -O file2.py, it opens it up in a new window. The link you posted shows how to split open multiple files at once, but for me, I want to know how, if I already have an open file, split open another file from the command line.. do you get what I mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following to split horizontally.

```
:split file2.py
```

Use the following to split vertically.

```
:vsplit file2.py
```

---

To close the current window just use `:q`.

---

Take a look at `:h windows.txt`

Comment: Hm, is there a way to open a file in another directory like that? Also, how would I close only one of the files which are open in splitscreen?

Comment: @user2719875 use the relative or absolute path?

Comment: perfect, thanks.. the relative path worked. Any idea on how to close one of the files which are open in splitscreen now?

Comment: @user2719875 You should read `:h windows.txt` it should contain all your answers

Comment: I often open `.` to browse for the file I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

```
:vsplit file2.py
```

Do the above to accomplish this.

Comment: thanks.. Any idea on how to close one of the files which are open in splitscreen?

Comment: :q.  To toggle between the screens, you can <CTRL-w><CTRL-w>